# Is there any tool to measure RAM usage in an A-Frame scene?

Tags: aframe

Per title, I'd like to know what is the best way to measure how much memory an application solely made in A-Frame is consuming. I have this collada model with a little bit over 6MB and spread images, and moving across this building seems to take an insane amount of RAM, rendering it barely usable in mobile devices.

Comment: Hmmm, should this have these tags at all? I'm not sure what makes `A-Frame` different than anything else that runs in the browser? What made you tag this question with `three.js`?

Comment: Perhaps good to have searchable for A-Frame/web developers that might not know that there are agnostic browser memory tools available.

Comment: But it still has nothing to do with aframe? Why not put jquery, babylon.js, openscenegraph.js, Scene.js etc etc? Why aframe, why three.js? It seems misleading and confusing, if following the searchable logic, we should post this exact same question a dozen more times, just tag it with different 3d frameworks. This way it sounds like aframe and three.js are super special, and not just javascript like any other javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use browsers' memory tools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Memory

Comment: Thanks, @ngokevin. I'm not an expert and wasn't looking correctly due to my lack of knowledge on this. Your answer was very helpful.